# Firebase Cross Platform Push Notification Plugin Duplicating MainActivity

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using the following [**plugin**](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin) for implementing and handling **FCM** push notifications in my xamarin application and there's one little unaddressed problem I'm facing.

I was hoping someone else has already figured it out and could help me.

### THE PROBLEM:

It seems to be duplicating my `MainActivity` although I have the `LaunchMode` set to `SingleTop`.

There's an event called **`OnNotificationReceived`** that's provided by the library.
This event fires as expected, **only once**, when the application is in the foreground.

When I minimize the application (let it run in the background), send a notification to the device and tap on the notification, it opens the application, as expected, but if I send another notification after that, while the application is in the foreground, The **`OnNotificationReceived`** Event is fired **twice**.

- I've tried changing the **`NotificationActivityFlags`** property to SingleTop.
- I've tried changing my `MainActivity`'s Launch Mode to `SingleTop`
- I tried running the sample application they've provided to check if its something that I'm doing wrong, and still the same thing happens.
- Logging the [**issue**](https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin/issues/249) in their Github repository

**None** of the above have worked.

**The issue can be reproduced by:**

1. downloading the sample from the repository, link provided above
2. replacing their google-services.json file with your own from the Firebase
   console.
3. change the package name of the sample of the application to the one you
   have registered on Firebase
4. following the steps above that I've mentioned

#### ADDITIONAL INFO

- Version Number of Plugin: **1.3.0**
- Device Tested On: **Huawei P8 Lite Android Version 6.0**
- Version of VS: **Visual Studio 2019**
- Version of Xamarin: **3.4.0.1009999**

Comment: There might be issue with your payload. Try to send only 'data' payload.

Comment: HI thanks for your input @r15 :), it seems to be working fine with only the data payload, but now, the notification has no title and no body

Comment: You need to give 'title' and 'body' keys with some data.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you correctly, do mean I must place the title and body keys inside the data payload?

Comment: I think those are reserved keywords like title, subtitle and body. Try it.

Comment: Okay I put the body and title in the data object and they're displayed. One problem though, according to the docs data messages don't display a notification on iOS. For  
iOS I'd have to include the notification payload as well, which seems to be the root of the problem right now.

Comment: Like that you will get many doubts/issues. For that you can ask different question :).

Answer (score 0):

### Update:

Unfortunately, the method below has not proven successful after attempting to implement it, I should have thought of the fact that I'm still going to need the notification object for iOS, earlier.

Myself and the team are going to implement a way to keep track of the users platform on the server and send them a notification either with or without the notification based on their platform, since iOS handles FCM notifications differently from Android. For now we're going to use Google's Instance ID service to determine what platform existing users are on.

#### Workaround:

I hope this helps someone in the future, if not I hope someone can provide me with a better solution.

In order to have my cake and eat it, basically be able to keep the notification object in the payload instead of removing it and having to further customise the payload to display notifications just for iOS, I changed the `MainActivity`'s (the activity thats launched when a user taps on the notification) Launch mode to `SingleInstance`. That way I can keep my notification object in the payload and not have to worry about the **`OnNotificationReceived`** event being triggered twice.